# Embeddable Common-Lisp asdf:defsystem returning invalid relative pathname

Tags: windows, common-lisp, asdf, ecl

I'm trying to learn how to use Common-Lisp's asdf, and I have the following code:

```
(asdf:defsystem example
    :serial t
    :components ((:file "first")
                 (:file "second")))
```

However, I keep getting the error:

```
Condition of type: SIMPLE-ERROR
Invalid relative pathname #P"first.lisp" for component ("example" "first")
```

I'm launching the repl in the same directory as these two Lisp files, but I don't understand why there is an error. What am I missing? I'm using ECL on Windows

Comment: Aside from storing the system definition in a file and then saying something like `(asdf:load-system "path/to/mysystem.asd")`, you can load a system which is defined in your Lisp session, as you are trying to do here, and the key part is to define `:pathname` to tell ASDF where to look for files. I posted what I was able to figure out in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74932862/871096

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ASDF uses `*load-pathname*` or `*load-truename*` to resolve the full paths to the system's components. If you enter the `(asdf:defsystem ...)` form on the REPL, these variables are not set.
Write the `defsystem` form into a file, then load it like `(load "example.asd")`.

Comment: Although it does work to write the system definition into a file, it's also possible to define it in the Lisp session. The key point is to supply `:pathname` to tell ASDF where to find the files.